# Retornar função do model no controller

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Preciso retornar uma função do model no meu controller como se fosse um "virtual" do Mongoose, na verdade no controller eu iria especificar via "populate" o nome da função e iria retornar o retorno da função no JSON de retorno da minha função do controller.

Eu faço isso em Laravel e queria saber se no Mongoose consigo fazer igual...

Segue códigos de exemplo:

Model:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Teste = mongoose.model('Teste');

const schema = new Schema({
    testeField: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true }});

schema.virtual('testeInclude', {
    ref: 'Teste',
    localField: 'testeField',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: false, // set true for one-to-one relationship
    options: { sort: { t: -1 } }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teste', schema);
```

Isso seria um virtual de 1 pra 1 ou 1 pra muitos...

Esse é o model que eu precisaria:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Teste = mongoose.model('Teste');

const schema = new Schema({
    testeField: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true }});

schema.virtual('testeInclude', function () {
    return 123;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teste', schema);
```

Abaixo retorno no controller com o populate:

```
var teste = function(req, res, next){
    Teste.find({}).populate("testeInclude").then(x => {
            res.status(200).send({ x });
        }
    }).catch(e => {
            res.status(200).send({ "error" });
    });
}
```

Aceito outras formas de fazer isso, não precisa ser com virtual e populate..Sugestões ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui algo parecido com o que preciso mas sem usar o populate, segue exemplo:
Usando a biblioteca **mongoose-fill**

**Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose-fill');
schema.fill('teste', function(callback){
    this.db.model('Model')
        .findById("5ddd80bafff20707a5434adb")
        .exec(callback)
});
```

**Controller:**

```
Model.find({}).fill('teste').then(x => {
    console.log(x);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```